# VBA to enable editing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to download an attachment from a secured site and open it using VBA.

While i'm trying to activate the workbook ( $workbook(Wb_name).Activate ), it throws some error and when I click on enable editing manually and try executing the same code it works fine.

Is there a way to enable the workbook from protected view before activating it.

Note : I have extracted the file name from the webpage. So don't have to bother about "Wb_name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to change the macro security settings programmatically to the lowest before you open the Excel workbook. After manipulating your data, re-enable the previous setting of the macro security

```
Public Sub MySubroutine()
Dim lSecurity As Long

lSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow

'''''''''''''''''''''
'   Run code here   '
'''''''''''''''''''''

Application.AutomationSecurity = lSecurity
```

End Sub

[this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/631545-change-trust-center-settings-visual-basic-applications.html:) link may also help you..

Comment: Thanks for you answer... but it doesn't suit my question... the issue is not with opening the workbook... it is actually with activating the workbook. Since it is in the protected view i cannot activate it. My query is how to disable the protected view i.e enable the editing.

Comment: Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit

 Just stick this line in an appropriate spot in your code and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

If the workbook you are trying to manipulate is the ActiveWindow then this code should help,

```vb
 If Not Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing Then
     Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
 End If
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It covers both the situations where the workbook is protected and where it isn't.